# Access to the same file after restart in the sandbox

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sandbox

My app reads iTunes' XML Library file under

```
/Users/username/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music Library.xml
```

However, if the iTunes Library is stored on a different hard disk, so will this file.
The sandbox doesn't allow me to access this file, unless the user grants it.

This is done using a `NSOpenPanel`.

However, now I'd have to ask the user for permission to access this file each time he opens up the app, which is pretty annoying.

Is there a way to permanently grant access to a specific file?

### EDIT

For example, if you open a file in another app, if you quit it the app will open the same file again. Something like this would be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is to use *security scoped bookmarks*. The outline of what you need to do is:

1. Check if you have a saved bookmark (see below), if so activate it. Done.
2. Have the user select a file/folder using `NSOpenPanel`
3. Take the URL that is returned and save it to disk as a security scoped bookmark - you save it somewhere in your container, your `NSUserDefaults` is one choice.

That's it. You need to read [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16) to understand the details.

Comment: You can use this open source class to wrap up the security scoped bookmarks into a simple interface. https://github.com/leighmcculloch/AppSandboxFileAccess