# Sandboxing Application: Partially Failing to Reading XML Plist

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, plist, sandbox, nsimage

I have an **NSMutableArray** of **NSMutableDictionary**.  The application allows the user to save the array as an **XML** project file with **plist**.  Everything works fine before the application is sandboxed.  The dictionary contains keys to store file names, image width, image height, file paths... all as strings.

Now, if I read a project file with **NSOpenPanel** while the application is sandboxed, things don't go well.  The application can read a project file since it enables **com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write**.  But it will fail to create an image with a file path.

```
- tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)TableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    NSString *imagename = [[imageArray1 objectAtIndex:rowIndex] objectForKey:key1a];

    if ([[TableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"images"]) {
        if ([self fileExists:imagepath]) {
            NSImage *image0 = :[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagepath]; // ==> failure 
            return image0;
        } else {
            return nil;
        }
    }
}

- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSInteger r1 = [tableview1 selectedRow];
    if (r1 >=0) {
        NSString *filepath = [[imageArray1 objectAtIndex:r1] objectForKey:key1b];       
        if ([self fileExists:filepath]) {
            pictureimage10.image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath]; // ==> failure 
        } else {
                    ...
        }
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

So if the application passes a file path to **NSImage**, it will display no image.  I wonder if there's something that I don't know about sandboxing applications?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Yes, you are missing security-scoped bookmarks, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842316/access-to-the-same-file-after-restart-in-the-sandbox/16844169#16844169)

Comment: I see.  So security-scoped bookmarks are required when you reopen a file outside of its container.  Thanks again.